# Casting actual type in C# return null value

Tags: c#

I have the following codes to fetch data from database:

**ICostCenterService:**

```
public interface ICostCenterService
{
    .
    .
    Task<string> GetAllCostCenters();
    .
    .
}
```

**CostCenterService:**

```
public class CostCenterService : ICostCenterService
{
    private readonly SqlServerContext _sqlServerContext;

    .
    .
    .

    public CostCenterService(SqlServerContext sqlServerContext)
    {
        _sqlServerContext = sqlServerContext;
    }

    async Task<string> ICostCenterService.GetAllCostCenters()
    {
        var costCenters = await _sqlServerContext.CostCenters.ToListAsync();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ServiceResultModel { Succeed = true, Result = costCenters });
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class ServiceResultModel
{
    public bool Succeed { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following method to fetch data:

```
async Task LoadCostCenters()
{
    var result = await _costCenterService.GetAllCostCenters();
    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResultModel>(result).Result as List<CostCenter>;
    
}
```

The problem is that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResultModel>(result).Result` has value but `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResultModel>(result).Result as List<CostCenter>;` returns `null`. I'm sure that the actual type is `List<CostCenter>`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: BTW, `async` functions should be named with an `...Async` suffix - so your method should be named `LoadCostCentersAsync` - and you should add a `CancellationToken` parameter and pass it down.

Comment: In `class ServiceResultModel` - why are you using `object` as the type for the `Result` property?

Comment: @Dai I use `object` because I want to make it a general type. I'd pass different types in other services.

Comment: "I'm sure that the actual type is `List<CostCenter>`" - well the results suggest otherwise. I suggest you use a cast instead of the `as` operator, and you'll see what it *actually* is. I'd also encourage you to provide a [mcve] - none of the async stuff is relevant; you're getting JSON string and deserializing it. A minimal example would just hard-code that JSON, deserialize it and the cast the `Result` property.

Comment: @JonSkeet When I use `var list = (List<CostCenter>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResultModel>(result).Result;`  there is an error in browsers console and says: `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ArtaNG_UI.Data.Models.CostCenter]'.`

Comment: Right, well there's your answer. The value of the `Result` property is a reference to a `JArray`, not a `List<CostCenter>`, which is why the `as` operator returned null. (Whenever you're "sure" of something but the results suggest otherwise, you should verify what you're "sure" of. In my experience, that feeling of certainty is usually misplaced.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Why cannot `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResultModel>(result).Result` return an object?

Comment: _"Why cannot JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResultModel>(result).Result return an object?"_ - it does. One of type `JArray`.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Create a model to deserialize to rather than writing `object`.

Comment: @AlexWright As a rule-of-thumb: if you ever use `Object` as a type in C#, with very few exceptions, _you're probably doing something wrong_. If you need a method/property to return or accept types belonging to a _finite_ set then use method overloads for each type or a union-type (like `OneOf<...>` on NuGet). If you control the types then use an `interface`. If you don't care about the type and/or it's controlled by your code's consumer then make your method a generic method. Etc. The only time I ever use `Object` is for `lock()` fields.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by making a general class:

```
public class ServiceResultModel<T>
{
    public bool Succeed { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

After that, I can use my desired types whenever I need.